# Android: Can't seem to theme SearchView

Tags: android

I've been trying real hard to theme SearchView. My min API is sdk 21 too, so I should be able to use the new styling options.

Specifically, I want the in-app-bar text field that appears when I click on the search icon to be theme-able. I want to ultimately make the background white, and the text/cursor either blue or black.

Here is my styles.xml. The last theme is the new SearchTheme I'm working on. The actual values don't matter, they're garbage values I threw in just trying to make a change happen.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PreferencesTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.SearchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:closeIcon">@drawable/contacts5icon</item>
        <item name="android:voiceIcon">@drawable/contacts5icon</item>
        <item name="android:queryBackground">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I've assigned the AppTheme.SearchTheme to the other main themes that I'm using in my layout. But nothing I do seems to have any effect. The values don't seem to change.

I haven't really messed with Android theming before, so I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get on the right track, per Chris Banes' walk-through for using material design on pre-lollipop androids. For you, in a nutshell: set item property searchViewStyle under your main style with a Widget.AppCompat.SearchView style extension.

You can use the queryBackground item property for altering the text field's background. Other properties are detailed below.

```
<style name=”Theme.MyTheme” parent=”Theme.AppCompat”>
<item name=”searchViewStyle”>@style/MySearchViewStyle</item> 
</style>
<style name=”MySearchViewStyle” parent=”Widget.AppCompat.SearchView”>
<!-- Background for the search query section (e.g. EditText) -->
<item name="queryBackground">...</item>
<!-- Background for the actions section (e.g. voice, submit) -->
<item name="submitBackground">...</item>
<!-- Close button icon -->
<item name="closeIcon">...</item>
<!-- Search button icon -->
<item name="searchIcon">...</item>
<!-- Go/commit button icon -->
<item name="goIcon">...</item>
<!-- Voice search button icon -->
<item name="voiceIcon">...</item>
<!-- Commit icon shown in the query suggestion row -->
<item name="commitIcon">...</item>
<!-- Layout for query suggestion rows -->
<item name="suggestionRowLayout">...</item>
</style>
```

more [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Comment: Honestly, I tried all of that a million times, and couldn't get anywhere. No idea what I'm doing wrong. Anyway, I decided to just settle for the default appearance to stop worrying about it. But seriously, queryBackground, for example, would never change anything.